# Error retrieving values from ObjectStateEntry

Tags: c#, entity

I try to create `Database` according [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542) tutorial.

This is my Class:

```
public abstract class File
{
    [Key]
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public double size{ get; set; }
}

public class SubFile: File
{
    public string secondName{ get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SubFile> subFile{ get; set; }
}
```

Main

```
var sb = new SubFile{ fileName = "test.doc" };
sb.secondName= "test2.doc";

using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    db.SubFile.Add(sb);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

After try to save got an error:

> *Error retrieving values from ObjectStateEntry. See inner exception for
>   details.*

Comment: What is the details part?

Comment: @user1860934, yes, the inner exception. What's the text of the inner exception?

Comment: nner exception is null, and message is The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced

Comment: We faced same type of error. It was due to extra property in edmx class that was not matching with table in database.

Answer (score 0):

My inner exception was **The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced**

The error would occur when calling SaveChanges on my database context after adding a new entity to the database.

To solve my problem I had to change my entity so that a **complex type** IPAddress was instead a string.